# Check whether a column in a dataframe is an integer or not, and perform operation

Tags: pandas

Check whether a column in a dataframe is an integer or not, and if it is an integer, it must be multiplied by 10

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.dataframe(....)    
#function to check and multiply if a column is integer
def xtimes(x): 
  for col in x:
    if type(x[col]) == np.int64:
        return x[col]*10
    else:
        return x[col]
#using apply to apply that function on df
df.apply(xtimes).head(10)
```

I am getting an error like ('GP', 'occurred at index school')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `dtypes` attribute and `loc`.

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes <= np.integer] *= 10
```

---

**Explanation**
`pd.DataFrame.dtypes` returns a `pd.Series` of numpy dtype objects.  We can use the comparison operators to determine `subdtype` status.  See [**this document**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html) for the `numpy.dtype` hierarchy.

**Demo**

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
]).astype(pd.Series([np.int32, np.int16, np.int64, float, object, str]))

df

   0  1  2    3  4  5
0  1  2  3  4.0  5  6
1  1  2  3  4.0  5  6
```

---

The `dtypes` are

```
df.dtypes

0      int32
1      int16
2      int64
3    float64
4     object
5     object
dtype: object
```

We'd like to change columns `0`, `1`, and `2`
Conveniently

```
df.dtypes <= np.integer

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

And that is what enables us to use this within a `loc` assignment.

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes <= np.integer] *= 10

df

    0   1   2    3  4  5
0  10  20  30  4.0  5  6
1  10  20  30  4.0  5  6
```

Comment: This is interesting, quite handy when dtype is specific.

Comment: @JohnGalt Updated to be less specific

Answer (score 4):

You could use `select_dtypes` to get numeric columns and then multiply.

```
In [1284]: df[df.select_dtypes(include=['int', 'int64', np.number]).columns] *= 10
```

You could have your specific check list for `include=[... np.int64, ..., etc]`

Comment: I guess you can also use np.issubdtype with np.integer or it might return all integers with that.

Comment: Actually `df.select_dtypes([np.integer])` does it.